# Influxdb says not authorized to exectute statement

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb

I'm facing some issues when I try to run a simple SELECT query on influxdb via the Python library.

I'm trying to run the following query:

```py
influx_client.query('SELECT * FROM "measurements" LIMIT 10;')
```

Of course I switched to the according database (and connected to the server) before executing the query. Also I tried those variants of the query:

```py
influx_client.query("SELECT * FROM \"measurements\" LIMIT 10;")
influx_client.query("SELECT * FROM 'measurements' LIMIT 10;")
influx_client.query('SELECT * FROM \'measurements\' LIMIT 10;')
influx_client.query('SELECT * FROM {0} LIMIT 10;'.format("measurements"))
influx_client.query("SELECT * FROM {0} LIMIT 10;".format("measurements"))
```

however they all lead to the same issue.

The result (or more the error) that I get is the following:

```
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 403: {"error":"error authorizing query: myuser not authorized to execute statement 'SELECT * FROM \"measurements\" LIMIT 10', requires READ on True"}
```

I know that my user have the required permissions because when connecting to the DB with a CLI I can execute the query. On top of that I checked the permissions with SHOW GRANTS and I could see that all requirements are satisfied (the user actualy does have all privileges).

I saw some simillar issues already (for instance in this [issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/issues/615)) however this does not fit my case since I'm quoting the query.

Informations about the environment:

- InfluxDB version: 1.8.0
- InfluxDB-python version: 5.3.1
- Python version: 3.6.8
- Operating system version: CentOS 7

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to check for the authentication issue:

1. https configuration with given private key and password certificate [Link](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/https_setup/)
2. Passing the user credentials for the influx db connection (Check the case sensitivity as well.

Have used influx and these are key configuration will lead to authentication issue.

using command CLI you need to provide the user permission to the given database

```
Using <you-database>

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO <username>
```

[Grant Permission To User](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/authentication_and_authorization/#grant-administrative-privileges-to-an-existing-user)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I already tried this possibilities unfortunately the error remains the same. I'm more than sure that my user is connected to the db since (for instance) I'm able to print all existings databases and even all tables.

Comment: No, show databases will show without authorization also. So measurements ?

Comment: But when I switch to the according database and execute show tables I do see the tables (measurements for isntance)

Comment: Are you able to authenticate and gets data using cli comand ?

Comment: Yes. From a cli everything works as it should.

Comment: When doing the very same with Java it works. So for me it looks lime it is an issue on the lib side. Maybe a missleading error message or something

Comment: @DeredleweißeRitter yeah if its working fine through cli then it should be working through code also. Check is there any issues on git for that lib

Comment: Well I opend one but no reply yet. Their is a similar one but it does not fit my case

Comment: @DeredleweißeRitter  you need to provide the permission to the user added query in the ans

Comment: I do not reall understand what oyu mean with your last commentr

Comment: @DeredleweißeRitter  use the this query for the granting permission GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO <username>     https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/authentication_and_authorization/

Comment: Ah I see. Well this is done and if I do SHOW PRIVILEGES I can see that my user have all required permission. Also the same query with same connection information works in Java but fails in Python. So for me it seem like their is an issue in the lib.

Comment: @DeredleweißeRitter yeah then check with lib